# Excel: Count after first three blank cells

Tags: excel-formula

Is there a way to sum after each three consecutive blanks in Excel? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E1QL.jpg)

[image]

the image is an illustration of the result I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B2:J2,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(D2:J2)/((B2:H2="")*(C2:I2="")*(D2:J2 = "")),1)):J2)
```

[image]

Comment: That depends on what you are looking for, your title says count while your narrative says sum.  Sum yes, count no. @hypercool1217

Comment: for count use: `=COUNTIF(INDEX(B2:J2,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(D2:J2)/((B2:H2="")*(C2:I2="")*(D2:J2 = "")),1)):J2,"<>")` instead.  Also if these work please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.